# Highlighting cursor column in ST2

Tags: sublimetext2

In Vim speak, `cursorcolumn` and `cursorline`. I'm certain that there is such an option somewhere, but I haven't been able to find it.

Does anyone know whether the editor supports it, and how to turn it on?

Just to be clear, what I'm looking for is this (screenshot of Vim).

[image]

Comment: Also, if someone could explain how to show a smaller picture when inserting pictures, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at CursorRuler:   https://github.com/icylace/CursorRuler

There is a little known undocumented (?) setting called `"inverse_cursor_state": true,` which (when put inside your personal settings) will turn the cursor 90 degrees so that it underlines the current character.

/Users/HOME/Library/Application Support/sublime text 2/Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings

```
{
  "auto_complete_triggers":
  [
    {
      "characters": "./\\()\"'-:,.;<>~!@#$%^&*|+=[]{}`~?",
      "selector": "text.shtml"
    }
  ],
  "color_scheme": "Packages/User/0.themes/0.lawlist.tmTheme",
  "find_selected_text": false,
  "font_face": "Courier",
  "font_size": 18.0,
  "forward_sync": true,
  "ignored_packages":
  [
    "Vintage",
    "PersistentRegexHighlight"
  ],
  "ignored_words":
  [
    "\\bf\\uline",
    "\\begin{singlespace*}",
    "Joinder"
  ],
  "inverse_cursor_state": true,
  "keep_focus": false,
  "scroll_past_end": true,
  "show_full_path": true,
  "word_separators": "./\\()\"'-:,.;<>~!@#$%^&*|+=[]{}`~?"
}
```